# How can I retrieve x number of violations?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to collect x number of violations, and the below code snippet works for one violation. How can I amend it to repeat the same process for x number of violations? `CustomError` is made up `of` 2 `String` values for reference.

```
private static Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();

Set<ConstraintViolation<Request>> violations =
    validator.validate(Request);

CustomError customError =
    CustomError.of(
        violations.iterator().next().getPropertyPath().toString(),
        violations.iterator().next().getMessage());

List<CustomError> errors = Collections.singletonList(customError);
```

Comment: Take the iterator and create a loop reading it? You are only taking the head of the iterator, but iterators are there to be iterated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you need to iterate over all violations and create custom error.

Here is code example:

```java
...
    public static class Error {
        private final String field;
        private final String message;

        public Error(final String field, final String message) {
            this.field = field;
            this.message = message;
        }

        public String getField() {
            return field;
        }

        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }
    }

    public Collection<Error> validate(Request request) {
        var validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
        var violations = validator.validate(request);
        return violations
            .stream()
            .map(v -> new Error(v.getPropertyPath().toString(), v.getMessage()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to match the List to a mapped stream but was struggling here, thanks!